# Problem with Volumetric fog in Cycles - low quality during rendering

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Hello I have problem with rendering in cycles I get quality like that like very much compressed video. How can I fix this problem?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, what does it give if you disable the Denoise option (also disable if you have any denoise in the Compositor)?

Comment: I attached 2 images above the lower one show the setup from shadder and on the right you can see the render setup. If you want to see more setting please let me know what to show

Comment: Yes I try to disable noise, then I have a lot of noise but still I have a lot of squares

Comment: This is how it looks without denoise https://imgur.com/a/aRD3cwP  There are still squares

Comment: For smoke simulations I can tell you, your _Transparency_ bounces under _Light Paths_ are much too low at 0. I'm not often doing fog, but with smoke using the _Principled Volume_ I set the bounces to at least 32, better even 64 or 128.

Comment: with more light bounce still have the same problem: https://imgur.com/a/S4uiu2M

Comment: Hmmm, well yeah it was just an idea, I know even YT tutorials about smoke simulations have those and sometimes the tutors claim it's a limitation of Mantaflow or using Adaptive Domain etc., though it's clearly not, just light bounces. From the settings alone I can't really see a problem, sometimes it is just something specific in a scene that's not working. But then it's hard to determine for us when we can't examine the scene directly.

Comment: Try to disable "Use Tilling" under Render properties > Memory ... does it make a difference?